# java script singleton behavior from session to session

Tags: javascript, session, object, singleton

I want to implement java script Singleton in my script. 
Some of the variables of the Singleton have the same values for all users, but others will very from user to user.

I want to understand better - is Singleton  create one instance for all the session running or every session will manage her own object. 
One of the variables will be logger/counter - will all the users/sessions share its value?

My object will look something like this:

```js
var VideoLog = (function () {
 
 /** logger vars **/
 this.logger = 0; 
 this.somevar = null;
  this.somefunction = function () {
     come code..
    }
       
    })();
```

Comment: With Javascript alone you can't share anything between users.  What you are describing is client side variables (Javascript vars, implemented as singletons where relevant), and application variables (implement on the server and shared between all clients).

Comment: "All users" can only share values from the server unless you implement some peer-to-peer network - you would likely still need a server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=singleton+%5Bjavascript%5D

Comment: @Archer What I am confused about is is Javascript  can't share anything between users, does this means that if I create a Singleton object in my js file, and in that file implement an incrimination of the logger variable, then every session will have its own value of the logger? Or will it be shared between all sessions, if it is increased it's increased  for all?

Comment: Javascript runs in your browser, on your PC.  It doesn't even natively share anything with the server that the web site is served from.  I think you've decided on a solution to a problem and now you want to know how to make that solution work, but it sounds like it's the wrong solution.  If you want something that is shared between all users then it _**must**_ live on the web server - the application that serves your web site.  So you're looking at PHP, ASP, ASP.Net etc..

Comment: @Archer I don't want it shared - I just wanted to make sure it won't. Thank you.

Comment: Okay then simply use vars in your scripts and they won't be shared anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The Singleton pattern is designed specifically to limit the number of instances of an object to one. This pattern is good for system-wide scripts.

I would suggest using the Constructor pattern. This way you can create a parent object that defines shared fields across objects. Then, create other objects from the parent which can have their own unique fields.

```
function Cat( breed, age ) {

  this.breed = breed;
  this.age = age;
}

var tabby = new Cat( "tibs", 3 );
var blue = new Cat( "Thomas", 6 );

tabby.color = 'orange';
blue.color = 'grey';
```